# Techniques of division by numbers in base n

Tags: soft-question, divisibility

Our current number system is in base 10, so we have devised techniques when a number is divided by a power of 10. For example: $\dfrac{350}{100} = 3.5$, by moving the decimal by two places because 100 has two zeros.

If we do division with numbers in base 2, or in any other base, would there be similar techniques? $\dfrac{1010}{10}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the same thing!

For instance, in base $2$, we have

$$\frac{1010}{100} = 10.1$$

This happens because the denominator is really $2^2$, while the numerator is $2^3+2^1$, and in base $10$, we have

$$\frac{2^3+2^1}{2^2} = 2^{3-2} + 2^{1-2} = 2^1 + 2^{-1} = 2.5,$$
which translates to $10.1$ in base $2$.

Comment: +1 Hah, I guess it's late and I've been doing too much math today. My first thought was like: "nice, there might be some categorical explanation behind this". Well, it is much easier (as you have shown) than that, although.. I mean, I don't know much about category theory, it's just that math can be very nice, when some answers are just corollary of more abstract thought. Ehm, I'd better get some sleep.